# Finding and printing ranges between IP addresses with bash

Tags: bash

I have this ip addresses that are in use in a file:

192.168.1.121
192.168.1.141
192.168.1.172
192.168.1.180
192.168.1.180
192.168.1.181
192.168.1.182
192.168.1.185
192.168.1.190

What I want to do is to be able to print out the ranges between used IP addresses with Bash. So for example by looking at the example 192.168.1.121 is used but I want to be able to print out all IP addresses between 121 and 141. Similarly between 141 and 172. I am not worried about printing IP addresses before 121 though.

Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks
Kuti.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

```
addresses=( `< listofnums` )
network=${addresses[0]%.*}
hosts=( ${addresses[@]##*.} )

for (( i=${hosts[0]}; i<255; ++i ))
do
        case "${hosts[@]}" in *"$i"*) ;; *) echo "$network.$i" ;; esac
done
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much and it seems to be working. Could you kindly explain. I am a bit new for bash.

Comment: Here's the section explaining parameter expansion (the instances of `${ }`):
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion
And the section explaining case:
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs